# How to do Generic Repository with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

I have set up my generic repository as follows:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : Entity
{
    T GetById(int id);
}

public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity
{
    protected readonly SqlDbContext _context = new SqlDbContext();

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }   
}
```

To enable dependency injection in my MVC app i also create a Product interface since the signature differs.  This is also the case for the other repositories.

```
public interface IProductRepository : IRepository<Product>
{
    IEnumerable<Product> GetDiscountedProducts();
}
```

And the implementation (note the inheritance)

```
public class ProductRepository : Repository<Product>, IProductRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetDiscountedProducts()
    {
        return _context.Set<Product>().Where(x=>x)...
    }           
}
```

Finally the repository gets injected into the MVC controller using unity

```
public HomeController(IProductRepository repository)
{
}
```

Is it just me or is this inheritance chain a bit messy here?  Is there any way to improve this design?

Comment: Im wondering what is gained by the `Repository<T>` and `IRepository<T>` pattern when it's passed as `IProductRepository` - you'll never see the `Repository<T>` implementation with that unless you cast, so it's kinda useless.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/01/16/ddd-the-generic-repository/

Comment: What does this attempt to achieve? (serious question)

What I have atm with my MVC3 project is 2 sets of objects (Queries and Commands ala CQRS), and each of them comes with a LINQ that hits a single Repository class that has access to all database objects. 

Where would having multiple repositories benefit me in this case? (I already know what each Command/Query does by its class name by convention)
And also, where does the dependency injection come into play?

At the moment this seems like overengineering to me, but I am interested to know.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the CQRS pattern, but having said that the  pattern i am heading towards is Domain Driven Design.  One of the concepts of DDD are Aggregate Roots, and this is spawning the needs for multiple repositories (which you are not seeing in this contrived example).  We are also using DI on the controllers for Unit Testing and some TDD.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest to avoid `IProductRepository` for this particular case (when simply adding single and very specific method) and enhance original IRepository interface as shown below:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable 
                 where TEntity : Entity 
{     
   TEntity GetById(int id); 
   IEnumerable<TEntity> List(IFilterCriteria criteria);
}
```

and then implement

```
public sealed class ProductDiscountFilterCriteria : IFilterCriteria 
{
   // ...
}
```

but in such case you've to define some logic to transform criteria to an query, it could be a LINQ Expression as you'are already using LINQ. If such creteria expression approach is complex for your case - I would suggest to stick with approach you've proposed.

**EDIT:** `IFilterCriteria` is simply [Query Object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html) pattern implementation

```
interface IFilterCriteria<TQuery>
{
   TQuery ToQuery();
}

public sealed class ProductDiscountFilterCriteria : IFilterCriteria<DynamicExpression>
{
  public decimal Discount { get; private set; }

  public DynamicExpression ToQuery()
  {
    // build expression for LINQ clause Where("Discount" > this.Discount)
  }
}
```

OR raw SQL criteria builder:

```
public sealed class ProductDiscountFilterCriteria : IFilterCriteria<string>
{
  public decimal Discount { get; private set; }

  public string ToQuery()
  {
    // simplified
    return "WHERE Discount < " + this.Discount;
  }
}
```

So then you would be able to use it like:

```
var products = productRepository.List<Product>(
                             new DiscountFilterCriteria { Discount = 50 });
```

Dynamic LINQ examples and articles:

- [Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)
- [Dynamic LINQ (A little more dynamic)](http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2010/08/04/dynamic-linq-a-little-more-dynamic.aspx)
- [Dynamic LINQ Part 2 (Evolution)](http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2010/08/19/dynamic-linq-part-2-evolution.aspx)

Comment: Could you elaborate the Filter concept a little with a simple example?

Comment: @Fixer : see EDIT part of my answer